# Magento 1.9 - Searching with quotes adds &quot; for next search

Tags: magento-1.9, search

So, whenever someone uses quotes in their search it works fine. However, when they go to search again the old search is stored in there and it replaces the quotes with their html entity ". This still works but is obviously annoying. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you use a search extension or custom module?

Comment: smartwave catalogCategorySearch

Comment: OK, could you reach out to them first? I'm sure they'll offer support on their module. Without knowing the ins and outs of the module you're using, it's very hard to give a suggestion.

Comment: Well when I turn the module off and do this in base theme its still happening. So no. Also they don't provide free support and i wouldn't pay $100 just for them to fix something they might have broke